# Wordpress WP ADmin ISsue

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, wp-admin

I have my website **https://getorganic.tech/** its First page(homepage) is opening fine but when i try to open admin panel **https://getorganic.tech/wp-admin/** . It cannot open and give me Page not reached error. i try many things like changing theme, Delete Plugins, Add website url in wp_config.php, I need your quick help Experts!

Answer (score 0):

You can try access the login page via /wp-login.php, although on further inspection the issue caused by too many redirects.

I think this is because you have forced HTTPS with a SSL certificate, so check you are not using a SSL plugin or HTTP to HTTPS redirects on the server.

Here is a good article to help you debug this issue: https://kinsta.com/blog/err_too_many_redirects/